# swapping img tags with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a hangman game where if the wrong letter is selected it adds a body part to the hangman model. I wanted it to show once the left arm is shown, the right arm is shown on the next letter entry. However they both show up on the first wrong entry

```
//JavaScript document
var answer = ['h', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'm', 'a', 'n'];
var wrong= ['b' ,'c' ,'d', 'e' ,'f' ,'i' ,'j' ,'k' ,'l','o' ,'p', 'q', 'r', 's' ,'t', 'u', 'v' ,'w', 'x' ,'y' ,'z'];
var letters = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
var answerLetter = document.getElementsByClassName("answer_char");
var letterpool= ['a ' ,'b ' ,'c ' ,'d ', 'e ' ,'f' ,'g ' ,'h ' ,'i ' ,'j ' ,'k ' ,'l ', 'm ' ,'n ' ,'o ' ,'p ', 'q ', 'r ', 's ' ,'t ', 'u ', 'v ' ,'w ', 'x ' ,'y ' ,'z '];
var leftarm = false

onload = init;
function init(){
    updateDisplay()

    document.getElementById("guess_button").onclick = function enter() {
        var userGuess = document.getElementById("guess_text").value;
        // This uses String.prototype.match() used too see if its both a letter and a single entry
        if(userGuess.match(letters) && userGuess.length === 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
                if (userGuess === answer[i])
                    // answer[i] correlates to answerLetter[i].
                    answerLetter[i].innerHTML = userGuess;
            }
            if(userGuess.match(letters) && userGuess.length === 1) {
                for (var i = 0; i < wrong.length; i++) {
                    if (userGuess === wrong[i])
                        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1].src="img/leftarm_on.png";
                    leftarm = true;
                }
                if(leftarm= true){
                    document.getElementsByTagName("img")[3].src="img/rightarm_on.png";
                }

            }
        }else {
            window.alert('please enter one letter, numbers need not apply .');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The `leftarm = true` assignment isn't inside the `if(userGuess === wrong[i])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>         if (userGuess === wrong[i])
>        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1].src="img/leftarm_on.png";
>        leftarm = true;
>        }
>        if(leftarm= true){
>            document.getElementsByTagName("img")[3].src="img/rightarm_on.png";
>        }
> ```

You're testing the conditions after each other here - and when you set `leftarm` in the first, it will already by true in the second. Btw, you are not using a `==` comparison but an `=` assignment; and actually there's no need to do that comparison at all. It should be

```
if (userGuess === wrong[i]) {
    if (!leftarm) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1].src="img/leftarm_on.png";
        leftarm = true;
    } else if (leftarm) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[3].src="img/rightarm_on.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured the else if would be the key, for what ever reason I kept getting an unexpected token with it though when I typed it. Must have done it wrong. Your version seems to work though. Thank you!

Comment: @moliminous: As barmar's edit shows, your second `if` statement was actually placed outside of the `for` loop. Placing an `else` there will give a syntax error. Lesson learnt: Always properly (auto-)indentate code, and find oddly placed parentheses!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this logic in your code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < wrong.length; i++) {
        if (userGuess === wrong[i])
       document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1].src="img/leftarm_on.png";
       leftarm = true;
       }
       if(leftarm= true){
           document.getElementsByTagName("img")[3].src="img/rightarm_on.png";
       }
```

Immediately after setting leftarm to true you then check to see if it's true and, if so, turn on the right arm.

Comment: I've already noticed that, but I was looking for a way to pause it for the next entry. I thought an else if may work, but the code is simply not having any of that. I get an unexpected else tag error when i do try to add it.

Comment: Why not swap the logic?  Check to see if left has already been set first?  In other words, invert the order of your checks.  Figure out if the answer is wrong.  If it is, left leg?  right leg? right arm? left arm? torso? head?  If the answer to head is false, set the head.  If the answer to head is true, turn on torso.  If the answer to torso is true, turn on left arm, etc.